# Is this bot from youtube a scam?

Tags: scam, bot

Thank you for reading my questions.
As a beginner in web3 and remix. I want to see others opinion first. Is this a scam or not.

Youtube video: `https://youtu.be/_a93BmDx258?si=cYc6NzMtIgwBHI0F`

Code:
`https://paster.icu/api/WyYfLRiBVe8`

I am concern because they suggest to use “remix.is”  not the official remix url. And the profit of the bot is too good to be true.

I checked the video comment, it seems to be 80% new user with weird name.
But there are some account that looks real which join YT from 2011 and has some real video.

What do you guys think?
Thanks